# embed PDF content in xulrunner

Tags: pdf, plugins, xulrunner, adobe-reader

On xulrunner 1.9.2 I could put the Adobe Reader plugin into /plugins of my xulrunner application and load content with:

```
    <vbox minwidth="200">

        <html   xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
            <div id="htmlDiv">

                <embed
                    id      = "pdfObject"
                    type    = "application/pdf"
                    src     = "chrome://manuals/content/test.pdf#toolbar=1&amp;navpanes=1&amp;scrollbar=1&amp;page=1&amp;view=FitH"
                    height  = "850px"
                    width   = "1100px"
                />
            </div>
        </html>

    </vbox>
```

I am moving now to xulrunner 17.0.1 and I couldn't get it to work - the Adobe Reader gives an error witin its own popup.

I checked the versions to what is in the current Firefox installation and it is correct. I also deleted pluginsreg.dat from the application profile - no success.

Any ideas on how to get back that content into xulrunner based apps would be great.

xuldev

Comment: Never mind - a chrome path was missing a trailing slash in the chrome.manifest ;)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - a chrome path was missing a trailing slash in the chrome.manifest ;)

Paul